# Findbugs-NP - NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH

Tags: java, findbugs

Findbugs is showing `NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH` for a line.

It says that there is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a `null` value will be dereferenced, which would generate a `NullPointerException` when the code is executed.

Of course, the problem might be that the branch or statement is infeasible and that the `null` pointer exception can't ever be executed; deciding that is beyond the ability of FindBugs.

**Here is the code:**

```
      public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
      {
         ....
         String sTypeName1 = row1.getFieldValue(OBJECT_TYPE_FIELD_NAME);
         String sTypeName2 = row2.getFieldValue(OBJECT_TYPE_FIELD_NAME);
         if (sTypeName1!= null && sTypeName1.indexOf("~") != -1)
         {
            sTypeName1 = m_oc.getString(sTypeName1);
         }
         if (sTypeName2!= null && sTypeName2.indexOf("~") != -1)
         {
            sTypeName2 = m_oc.getString(sTypeName2);
         }

         int cf = sTypeName1.compareTo(sTypeName2);
         if (cf == 0)
         {
            cf = o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
         }

         return cf;
       }
```

It is showing 2 errors of same kind for the code:

```
int cf = sTypeName1.compareTo(sTypeName2);
```

Here it says that there is a possible null pointer dereference from the value loaded from `sTypeName1`.

So I had to put a `null` check before this code like:

```
if(sTypeName1 != null && sTypeName2 != null)
{
  int cf = sTypeName1.compareTo(sTypeName2);
}
```

but the issue is not resolved. :(

Could anyone suggest a solution and also what is wrong with my approach?

Thanks a lot for going through my question :)

Comment: the other error which it shows is the same but when wrt compareTo().

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue is resolved. This code does not produce a bug report:

```
String sTypeName1 = row1.getFieldValue("qqq");
String sTypeName2 = row2.getFieldValue("www");
if (sTypeName1 != null && sTypeName1.indexOf("~") != -1) {
    sTypeName1 = m_oc.getString(sTypeName1);
}
if (sTypeName2 != null && sTypeName2.indexOf("~") != -1) {
    sTypeName2 = m_oc.getString(sTypeName2);
}
int cf = 0;
if (sTypeName1 != null && sTypeName2 != null) {
    cf = sTypeName1.compareTo(sTypeName2);
}
if (cf == 0) {
    cf = o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
}

return cf;
```

Probably you did not recompile your code or did not perform the FindBugs analysis again.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this can be caused by situations like this:

**Situation 1** - Findbugs will complain if you only set **b** under some conditions, such as if **a** is not null, then later reference b.  If **a** could really be null, you need to handle what to do if **b** is null too as a result.  If **a** is never null, remove the null check.  Also, for me it identified the line where **b** was defined as the first problematic line, rather than when **b.doSomething()** is called.

```
if (a != null) {
b = a.getB();
}

b.doSomething();
```

**Situation 2** - You nullcheck in one place, but not another.  Nullcheck everywhere, or nowhere

```
if (x != null) {
x.doSomething1();
}

x.doSomething2();
```